# Submit Form in Php lost @ character

Tags: php, javascript, forms

I've a very strange problem in my form and have no idea how to solve it. Tried a search but found nothing about it. I have a form which i receive the data with $get in a php page to process the data. Strangely, when i insert an @ in a field like the email for example, the @ is lost durring the process of sending data. I verified in the line before the redirection to the php page if the @ was there and it was, so i don't know this character is lost in the next step of the process.

Any hints?

The redirection comes from a javascript function that i call when i click the submit form:

```
window.location.href = 'index.php?pagina=candidaturasB&'+ qstringA;
```

the "qstringA" contains all the data of my form, and if in some input i put an @, if i do alert(qstringA) before de redirection line, the @ is there, after that, in the url, of the php page where i received the data there's no @.

ex: index.php?...&email="ren@something.com" appears on the url "index.php?...&email="rensomething.com".

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Comment: stripping special characters?

Comment: Sounds to me like you are using the email address as a *key*, not a *value* and PHP is eating the `@` and converting it to a `_` for compatibility with [`register_globals`](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php). Setting aside for a minute the fact that this is a stupid and annoying "feature" of PHP, which still happens in 5.4 *despite* the fact `register_globals` itself has actually now been *removed* - I think what you need to do is make sure you are transmitting the value *as a value*, and pass it through [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/urlencode) for the redirect.

Comment: I updated my initial post.
DaveRandom, like a key? Can you be more specific? I'm just retrieving the data from inputs, nothing more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `urlencode()` for each form data :

eg :

```
$url = "index.php?pagina=candidaturasB";
$url .= "&email=".urlencode($_GET['email']);
$url .= "&data="urlencode($_GET['data']);
```

And pass the result string to `window.location.href`

Comment: Loic i just use $_GET on the page where i receive the data, in the javascript function i mentioned i get the value of the input using:

var email=document.getElementById("email").value;

Sorry i forget to mention this before

Comment: Ok so your problem is a JS problem, not PHP. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/how-to-encode-a-url-in-javascript